# Randomly colorize UIButton how to avoid text (black) and background (white) color?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, random, uikit

I have a UIButton consists of a title text and a single color background. The button is drawn on the white UIView, and the title text is black.

I want to randomly colorize the button's background every time I launch the app. 
Here is my implementation:

```
#define KEY_COLOR_R @"KEY_COLOR_R"
#define KEY_COLOR_G @"KEY_COLOR_G"
#define KEY_COLOR_B @"KEY_COLOR_B"

+ (void)setThemeColorRandomly {

    //TODO: THEME COLOR NEEDS TO BE EASILY DISTINGUISHABLE WITH BLACK AND WHITE
    float r = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1];
    float g = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1];
    float b = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1];

    [ModuleHelper cache_setFloat:r forKey:KEY_COLOR_R];
    [ModuleHelper cache_setFloat:g forKey:KEY_COLOR_G];
    [ModuleHelper cache_setFloat:b forKey:KEY_COLOR_B];
}

+ (UIColor *)themeColor {

    float r = [ModuleHelper cache_floatForKey:KEY_COLOR_R];
    float g = [ModuleHelper cache_floatForKey:KEY_COLOR_G];
    float b = [ModuleHelper cache_floatForKey:KEY_COLOR_B];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1];
}
```

the `+setThemeColorRandomly` is called in `-didFinishLaunching`

And now I set the color:

```
[self.settingsButton setBackgroundColor:[CacheHelper themeColor]];
```

The problem is, I need to avoid the colors those are too light (mix with background) or too dark (mix with text). But I don't want to limit the diversity of colors, e.g. If I set the range to be 0.4-0.6 for all 3 colors, then I will miss red color, which is easily distinguishable with both white and black

EDIT:

The color I need to avoid is not just complete black and white. I need to avoid all the colors that are barely distinguishable.

The critical part is "distinguishable". for example, a very very light blue background is a bad choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a hsb color model, this way you have full control over the brightness of your color:

```
//set your color randomly
CGFloat hue = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1]; 
//you may play around with the saturation to get more colors as well
CGFloat saturation = 1; 
//adjust your desired min max values
CGFloat brightness = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0.3 high:0.7];

return [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
```

Comment: it's quite easy to tune the brightness to distinguish from the black and white.

Comment: with the help of photoshop, I get quite a good result with hue(0-1) saturation(0.4-1) and brightness(0.8-1)

Answer (score 1):

See my example:

```
float r,g,b;

do {

    r = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1];
    g = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1];
    b = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1];

} while(r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 0);
```

in this case `r g` and `b` are recalculated if are all `0` (i.e. black color).

If instead on of them is different from 0, is ok.

You can extend the example for all `1` as well (white color).

In your case you can simply avoid the whit background on the button, and then all equal couple of color:

```
float r,g,b, r1,g1,b1;

//Calculate the background different from white
do {

    r = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1];
    g = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1];
    b = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1];

} while(r == 1 && g == 1 && b == 1);

//Calculate the text color different from the background
do {

    r1 = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1];
    g1 = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1];
    b1 = [Helper getRandomFloatBetweenLow:0 high:1];

} while(r1 == r && g1 == g && b1 == b);
```

Or if you want use a range of tonality to be sure that the 2 color are enough different, you can use for example this last while:

```
} while(ABS(r1-r) > 0.3 && ABS(g1-g) > 0.3 && ABS(b1-b) > 0.3);
```

this is the function, you can choose your preference and tolerance.

Here the result:

[image]

Comment: The color I need to avoid is not just complete black and white. I need to avoid all the colors that are barely distinguishable

Comment: And what is the problem? with this code you can implement what you want

Comment: i think  `isSimilar` function to return ABS(r1-r2) < 0.3 && ABS(g1-g2) < 0.3 && ABS(b1-b2) < 0.3; is better